# Is it possible to generate renditions of data using alfresco DM forms?

Tags: alfresco

I currently use Alfresco XForm renditions to generate JSON data for our website. I am looking to move to Alfresco DM forms to do this but have read that DM forms do not support renditions, and I will need to use content transformation to generate JSON.
Has anyone attempted a similar move from XForms to DM forms who could give me advice?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, via the [Rendition Service](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Rendition_Service).  This is basically an enhanced version of the (limited) WCM XForms renditioning functionality, and operates within the DM repository rather than being limited to the legacy AVM repository.